# How to get all dates in sequence for a group by query?

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by

I am writing an analytic query on a user activity log table in Postgres 9.3. It has a sign-up date, a data field (that can be summed) and a user type. I've constructed some sample data/sql for this problem and I'm hoping to get some help figuring out the last part. The SQL required to test is below - it will drop/create a table called facts - so be sure to work in a sandbox.

I aggregate the data by week and user type - so you get a count of the data field for each user type every week. The problem I have is that I get results that are missing a week for user type = 'x'. Because there is no user data in week 9-9-13 for user type 'x' no row appears (see sample results below). I'd like there to be a row for that user type and week. I'd like to accomplish this, if possible with a single select statement, with no temp or dimension tables (this is because I will pass this sql off to a business manager and a single self contained SQL select statement is hopefully more fool proof (criticism on this approach is welcome but not an answer). Thank you all for any assistance!

Here's the results I get:

```
Sum     test_week       user_type
4   "2013-09-02"    "x"
5   "2013-09-02"    "y"
10  "2013-09-09"    "y"
2   "2013-09-16"    "x"
1   "2013-09-16"    "y"
```

Here's the results I want:

```
Sum     test_week       user_type
4   "2013-09-02"    "x"
5   "2013-09-02"    "y"
0   "2013-09-09"    "x"
10  "2013-09-09"    "y"
2   "2013-09-16"    "x"
1   "2013-09-16"    "y"
```

Here is the test data and SQL select statement:

```
drop table if exists facts;
create temp table facts (signup_date date, data integer, record_type varchar, alt varchar);
insert into facts (signup_date, data, record_type) values
('9/3/2013',1,'x'),
('9/4/2013',1,'y'),
('9/5/2013',2,'x'),
('9/6/2013',3,'y'),
('9/7/2013',1,'x'),
('9/8/2013',1,'y'),
-- note the week of 9/9 to 9/16 has no 'x' records
('9/9/2013',2,'y'),
('9/10/2013', 3, 'y'),
('9/11/2013', 4, 'y'),
('9/12/2013', 1, 'y'),
('9/17/2013', 2, 'x'),
('9/18/2013', 1, 'y');

select coalesce(data, 0), test_week, record_type
  from 
    (select sum(data) as data, record_type, to_timestamp(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM signup_date) || ' ' || EXTRACT(WEEK FROM signup_date),'IYYY IW')::date as test_week
    from facts
    group by record_type, test_week
    ) as facts
  order by test_week, record_type
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select
    coalesce(sum(data), 0) as "Sum",
    to_char(date_trunc('week', c.signup_date), 'YYYY-MM-DD') as test_week,
    c.record_type as user_type
from
    facts f
    right join
    (
        (
            select distinct record_type
            from facts
        ) f1
        cross join
        (
            select distinct signup_date
            from facts
        ) f2
    ) c on f.record_type = c.record_type and f.signup_date = c.signup_date
group by 2, 3
order by 2, 3
;
 Sum | test_week  | user_type 
-----+------------+-----------
   4 | 2013-09-02 | x
   5 | 2013-09-02 | y
   0 | 2013-09-09 | x
  10 | 2013-09-09 | y
   2 | 2013-09-16 | x
   1 | 2013-09-16 | y
```

Comment: Thanks! Your answer makes sense using a right outer join with an interior cross join as a "virtual" dimension table to force all the dates * record_type row combinations regardless of source data. I'm accepting your answer as the correct answer b/c Gordon Linoff's SQL is slightly harder to read using a left outer join, where the dimension table is the primary table and the fact table is the joined table. I think your system with right outer join is easier to understand. Both answers are equivalent I think.

Comment: @Steve Yes they are equivalent. There is one more detail in my answer that is the use of `date_trunc` which is easier to use than concatenating `extract`s. Also it is applied to the final set only.

Comment: yes I noticed those improvements. They're a good reason why your solution is better than the one I developed. By putting the sum on the outermost query, you avoid the ugliness of my inner cross join (answer below). Nice SQL and thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

To solve this problem, create a list of all combinations of all `record_type`s and all test weeks.  The left join from those combinations to the actual fact table.  This will give all the records, so you should be able to get the rows where there is no data:

```
select coalesce(sum(f.data), 0) as data, rt.record_type, w.test_week
from (select distinct record_type from facts) rt cross join
     (select distinct to_timestamp(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM signup_date) || ' ' || EXTRACT(WEEK FROM signup_date),'IYYY IW')::date as test_week
      from facts
     ) w left outer join
     facts f
     on f.record_type = rt.record_type and
        w.test_week = to_timestamp(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM f.signup_date) || ' ' || EXTRACT(WEEK FROM f.signup_date),'IYYY IW')::date
group by rt.record_type, w.test_week
order by w.test_week, rt.record_type;
```

Answer (score 0):

After playing around with some SQL myself, I have another solution which also works. I'm pretty sure this query is less performant than Clodoaldo Neto's or Gordon Linoff's, but I thought I'd share another form of SQL that solves the problem as well:

```
  select coalesce(data, 0), rt as record_type, weeks
    from 
      (select sum(data) as data, record_type, to_timestamp(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM signup_date) || ' ' || EXTRACT(WEEK FROM signup_date),'IYYY IW')::date as test_week
      from facts
      group by record_type, test_week
      order by record_type, test_week) as facts
    right join 
      (select distinct to_timestamp(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM signup_date) || ' ' || EXTRACT(WEEK FROM signup_date),'IYYY IW')::date as weeks, rts.rt as rt
       from facts
       cross join (select distinct record_type from facts) as rts (rt) 
       cross join (select distinct alt from facts) as alts (at)) as dates
    on dates.weeks = facts.test_week
    and dates.rt = facts.record_type
```